# Loading an animation during Retrofit 2 requests

Tags: android, dialog, retrofit2, loading

I am making an android application with a lot a activities and Retrofit 2 requests and I want to know what are the best practices for the loading animations during a request ?

Actually, I use my loading animation like this :

```
public void getLogin() {

      showDialog();

      retrofitService.getLogin(new Callback<SignInResponse>() {
         @Override
         public void onResponse(Call<SignInResponse> call, Response<SignInResponse> response) {

             hideDialog()
              //My stuff
          }

         @Override
         public void onFailure(Call<SignInResponse> call, Throwable t) {

              hideDialog()
              //My stuff again
          }
 });
}

public void showDialog() {

      ProgressDialog mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this); //Which is deprecated
      mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
      mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");

      if(mProgressDialog != null && !mProgressDialog.isShowing())
          mProgressDialog.show();
}

public void hideDialog() {

      if(mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing())
          mProgressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

I know that ProcessDialog is deprecated since API26 so if you have better ideas, I'll take them !
But it seems like I need to copy past every time this code when I do a requests and I wonder there is a better way to do that.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: you can use progressbar & set its visibility as `VISIBLE` or `INVISIBLE`

Comment: But I need to do that for every request. I am looking for a global use

Comment: You cant make it globally. Instead you can try search for Singleton methodology and implement you retofit calls according to it.